# Hive JDBC connection setting or mapping with MySQL

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am new to big data; technically I am a Java developer and decided to learn big data concepts. I am just able to install Hadoop and Hive, and now I want to connect my Java program to Hive. I have configured MySQL as a back-end db.

Tried to Google it and found a few Java program sample where they are using something like this URL `jdbc:hive2://172.16.149.158:10000/default,"",""`.

My question is I didn't made any setting like this in `hive-sites.xml`. Where should I made these setting or if not than where to find out which setting I should use?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: hands up .... sir

Answer (score 0):

Port 10000 is the default port for `HiveServer2`, which enables clients to execute queries against Hive.

This configuration is set in `hive-site.xml` via the property `hive.server2.thrift.port`

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
  <value>10000</value>
</property>
```

More details on `HiveServer2` are [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2)

Also, the `default` in the URL is the default Hive database.

Comment: where is the url setting and how to change default db ??

Comment: You can create a database in Hive: > create database mydb;

Comment: The URL is provided via HiveServer2. You may find this documentation helpful: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC