# Spring Controller not getting Scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Controller and project structure:

I am new to Spring Development. I am working on a web application. There are some jsp pages where I need to show some images so I made a resource entry in `spring-servlet.xml` like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/schedules/**" location="/schedules/" />
```

But as I am adding this entry after that my controller classes stop scan and non of my action detecting in says 404. but if am removing above entry from xml than my controllers detected properly. but after removing images urls are not found what am missing.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />
```

Comment: The base-package is supposed to point to **your** package **not** springs

Comment: actually my package name is spring

Comment: Show your controller code and project structure

Comment: Can you try with this : <mvc:resources location="/",mapping="/resources/**"/>

Comment: @ScaryWombat https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrQTy.png

Comment: @SandeepRathore its same whats in my question

Comment: Does not seem to `com.spring` though

Comment: @VikasKumar not same check once.

Comment: @ScaryWombat check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5nYU.png

Comment: @SandeepRathore tried its not working

Comment: @ScaryWombat ????? any update ???

Comment: Hmm. It looks like [in April, you posted this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50073794/472495), and I'd asked you not to ask volunteers for priority treatment ("urgent"). You acknowledged my message, and yet you are doing the same again. Is there a way I can encourage you to exercise patience, other than downvoting? Please remember that volunteers are under no obligations here.

Comment: If you genuinely need immediate attention, there are freelancer websites you can go to, where you can pay for immediate private help on an hourly basis. Let me know if you need some recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the mvc XML namespace is at `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` in your Spring servlet-context xml configuration.
2. The `<resources>` tag was introduced in Spring 3.0.4, so you need at least that version of Spring and of the xsd.

Comment: this is my spring conf

Answer (score 0):

1. My recommendation is use latest spring version.
2. add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your config files
3. check the resources folder line `<mvc:resources mapping="/schedules/**" location="/schedules/" />` is everything under this folder.

Comment: i have tried this is <mvc:annotation-driven /> too. but didnt make any diff. let me switch spring to latest version too. and under schedules some auto generated images came. nothing else

Comment: Please share your web.xml, controller class (current picture not giving the any clue about the annotation used on class), resource path picture

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To all For your Kind Support. issue is resolved. actually there is a level of hierarchy in which xml tag should declare.

Below code works for me

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/schedules/**" location="/schedules/" /> 

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

now my xml is looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/schedules/**" location="/schedules/" /> 

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="ApplicationResources" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```